# Why $|\alpha|\lt 1$ and $|\beta| \gt 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 117 he writes:

[image]

I didn't understand why $|\alpha|\lt 1$ and $|\beta| \gt 1$. I could only prove $\beta\lt -1$.

Answer (score 4):

If you have proved that $\beta <-1$ then you have proved that $|\beta| \gt 1$.

Since $\alpha\beta=1$, $|\alpha| |\beta|=1$. So if $|\beta| \gt 1$ then $|\alpha| \lt 1$

Comment: Why if I have proved that $\beta \lt -1$, then I have proved that $|\beta|\gt 1$?